# Sliding Menu jar file - Mono for Android

Tags: jar, xamarin.android

I would like to implement a sliding menu in mono for android.  It appears that what I need is the .jar file.  Where do I get the .jar file?  I do not use Eclipse.

The source is here: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

How to implement (once you have a .jar file) was answered here: [Monodroid sliding menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417126/monodroid-sliding-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find bindings in Xamarins [monodroid-samples repository](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SlidingMenu). They have been updated recently.

Comment: The sample doesn't appear to work.  I get the main screen and no sliding action.

Comment: I logged this with xam yesterday. Try changing the button handler to call ShowMenu()